# Function keys on the apply keyboard with no root

Tags: keyboard, apple, xmodmap

There is a well-known method on how to make function keys work on Apple keyboards in Ubuntu: `echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`
However, is there a way to do that with no root? Perhaps through `xmodmap` or `xsession`?
Thanks!

---

UPDATE:

I've got the desired behavior for a few selected keys using `xmodmap` (it was a bit annoying as I had to launch a separate X to stop the media key being intercepted by Gnome, but at the end I've got a keycode).
So I guess I've found a workaround. A more general solution would be very welcome, of course.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior ?

Comment: @wilf I'm not sure what do you mean, all the ways there assume that the person has root access.

Comment: Once again - no, I do not have root access (the machine is administered by the institution).

Comment: Then how can you run `echo 2 | ...`? :-s  You'll have to try keyboard settings then, as quite alot of ways of sorting this out require the use of `su..` commands.

Comment: I can't run `echo 2`, this is precisely my problem

Comment: If you found a (temporary) solution, would you mind posting it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: (This should be an edit but I'm too late) I could find the keycodes for F1 and F2 by grepping "Brightness", F7 to F12 with "Audio", but I'm still clueless for F3 to F6.